# getting the popup box controls values into controllers page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a ajax popup box where I am using 3 text_field `current_password` , `new_password` , `re-enter password` , but when I click on `Submit` button, I am not having the popup box controls value into a 
controllers page, below is the button that opens the popup box:

```
<table align="center" width="73%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:right;">
                        <div class="button">
                            <a id="ResetPass" class="buttonSearch">Reset</a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

And below is the javascript code that use to open the popup box:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                var el=document.getElementById("ResetPass");
                el.onclick = show_dialog2;
                function show_dialog2() {
                $( "#dialog" ).dialog();

                }
</script>
```

And below is the popup box div:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Reset Password" type="hidden">
                <%= form_tag({ controller: "settings", action: "reset_password"}, remote: "true" ) do |f| %>
                    <table style="text-align:center; vertical-align:top;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <%= label_tag(:currentpassword, "Current Password") %>
                                    <%= password_field :tf_currentpassword, :placeholder => "Current Password" %>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <%= label_tag(:newpassword, "New Password") %>
                                    <%= password_field :tf_newpassword, :placeholder => "New Password" %>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <%= label_tag(:re_enterpassword, "Re-enter Password") %>
                                    <%= password_field :tf_re_enterpassword, :placeholder => "Re=enter Password"  %>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr> 
                    </table>
                    <table align="center" width="63%">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:right;">
                                <%= submit_tag 'Submit', :id => "_button" %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                <% end %>
</div>
```

And below is the javascript for submitting the popup form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // '_button' is the Id of your submit button
    $("#_button").click(function() {            
      $(this).closest("form").submit();
      $("#dialog").dialog("close");
    });
});
</script>
```

I am getting an error below:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

For resolving this issue I add `authenticity_token: "true"` like below:

`<%= form_tag({ controller: "settings", action: "reset_password", authenticity_token: "true"}, remote: "true" ) do |f| %> 
<% end %>`

Then I am getting another error:

```
Missing template settings/reset_password, application/reset_password with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/Sites/MentorMentored1/app/views"
```

And below is the controllers page where I want to get popup controls values:

```
def reset_password
    @cp = params[:tf_currentpassword]
    @np = params[:tf_newpassword]
    @rp = params[:tf_re_enterpassword]    
  end
```

kindly help me waiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above error is related to view, not related to controller. There is no view for your reset_password action. And to check the parameters in controller debug the params hash using logger
e.g.

```
def reset_password
    Rails.logger.info "\n\n\n******#{params.inspect}******\n\n\n"
end
```

and check the log file for parameters(log/development.log for development environment). I guess you are getting parameters in controller.
You can check how to debug the rails app on this [page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html)